# Check values in other forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to pass the value of an int variable created in Form1 to another form. I tried by making the variable public and make this public partial class extended by Form1, but it copies all elements  Form1 to the other form. Is there another way? Thanks

Comment: please add some code and also what you tried so far..

Comment: Please post your code. You should be able to do var form = new Form(); form.PropertyValue = 2; form.Show();

Comment: Thank you guys, it worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a constructor by overloading

```
//called form code
public Form5(string Work_Order)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        string wo=Work_Order;
}


// calling form code
Form5 f5 = new Form5(Work_Order1);
f5.Show(); //or f5.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the value through a parameterized constructor
if you're in Form1 and you need to pass a value to other form use this instead.In Form1:

```
int a = 7;
form2 f = new form2(a);
f.show();
```

and in form2 make a constructor

```
int a;
public form2(int num){
this.a = num;
}
```

and use this variable 'a' throughout the form2.